# android activity: how to avoid multi-activity because time-delay

Tags: android, android-activity

I use remote or keyboard with android.
I have a list in XActivity and when keyPress listitem and start YActivity, and there some data need download before YActivity, so, when keyPress, there exist a time-delay, about several seconds later and then pop up one YActivity.

BUT at that seconds time-delay, person can move the focus and pressed again, another YActivity pop again.

how to avoid this.

```
    Intent i = new Intent(this, YActivity.class);
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putSerializable("ID", id); 
    i.putExtras(b);
    startActivityForResult(i, 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

1. When you press to open the YActivity then 
   the process means download you are doing shall be done in background **not in UI thread** You can use **Asynch Task OR Threads**
2. You can disable the button which started the YActivity

```
    Intent i = new Intent(this, YActivity.class);
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putSerializable("ID", id);
    i.putExtras(b);
    startActivityForResult(i, 1);
    btn.setEnabled(false);
```

1. And also you can set a Flag(like isStartingYActivity) and check if it is begin start

```
    if(!isStartingYActivity)
    {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, YActivity.class);    
        Bundle b = new Bundle();    
        b.putSerializable("ID", id);     
        i.putExtras(b);    
        startActivityForResult(i, 1);    
        isStartingYActivity = true;     
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use AsyncTask in you YActivity to load data.

"AsyncTask enables proper and easy use of the UI thread. This class allows to perform background operations"

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As soon as the button is clicked to move to the new activity. Make the button disabled. Like this. yourButton.setEnabled(False); This will prevent from double clicking on the button. Take the user to the new activity which he wants to go to and implement Async Task in new Activity and show a progress dialog from pre execute  of asynctask so that the user will know that the new activities data is getting loaded.